# Cannot display values of cascading drop-down list - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I created cascading dropdown list using asp.net, jQuery and ajax but 500 error (Internal Server Error) displayed, can anyone help me plzz :( ?

[image]

this is my function in the controller

```
        public JsonResult PopulateRecTypes(int employeeid)
    {
        MarketEntities db = new MarketEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<SelectListItem> Items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<marketingrectypeModel> MyRecType = (from c in db.marketingrectypes
                              join v in db.BookTypes
                              on c.id equals v.RecTypeId
                              join t in db.HandleBookReceipts
                              on v.BookTypeId equals t.BookTypeId
                              join b in db.BookResposibilities
                              on t.BookReceiptId equals b.HandleBookReceiptId
                              join x in db.Employees
                              on b.EmployeeId equals x.EmployeeId
                              where x.EmployeeId == employeeid && c.OrgId == (Int32)Session["OrgId"] && c.LicenceId == (Int32)Session["GLobalLicenseId"]
                              select new marketingrectypeModel() { id = c.id, name = c.name }).ToList<marketingrectypeModel>();


        foreach (marketingrectypeModel Recty in MyRecType)
        {

            SelectListItem selectList = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = Recty.name,
                Value = Recty.id.ToString()
            };
            Items.Add(selectList);
        }

        marketingrectypeModel Recs = new marketingrectypeModel()
    {
        MyRec = Items
    };
        return Json(Recs.MyRec, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is my rezor page

```html
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ReceiptTypeId, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control m-input", @id = "rectype" })
```

this is javascript code

```js
   $('#empList').change(function () {
        var selectedvalue = $("#empList option:selected").val();
        $.get("/BookRequests/PopulateRecTypes", { employeeid: selectedvalue }, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#rectype").append("<option value='" + row.Value + "'>" + row.Text + "</option>");
            });
            
        });
    });
```

can any one help me :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide exception detail but it seems there is an issue with Entity Framework.

You need to project out session values `Session["OrgId"]` and `Session["GLobalLicenseId"]`: before you send it off to be translated:

```
 var orgId = (Int32)Session["OrgId"];
 var licenceId = (Int32)Session["GLobalLicenseId"];
 
 List<marketingrectypeModel> MyRecType = (from c in db.marketingrectypes
                              join v in db.BookTypes
                              on c.id equals v.RecTypeId
                              join t in db.HandleBookReceipts
                              on v.BookTypeId equals t.BookTypeId
                              join b in db.BookResposibilities
                              on t.BookReceiptId equals b.HandleBookReceiptId
                              join x in db.Employees
                              on b.EmployeeId equals x.EmployeeId
                              where x.EmployeeId == employeeid && c.OrgId == orgId && c.LicenceId == licenceId
                              select new marketingrectypeModel() { id = c.id, name = c.name }).ToList<marketingrectypeModel>();
```